# athletic response light trainer by arduino

Tags: arduino, response, led, cc

currently I am trying to develop a light response trainer by arduino , as a beginning I used 3 led and 3 push button ,the led must work randomly and when the ledx is flash the user press push bottonx and so on 
of course I must use approximate sensor or something similar to be more reliable

when uploading  following code all leds continuous week glow (flash) what the problem? thanks for help.

```
 int ledselect = 0;
int led1 = 11; 
int led2 = 12; 
int led3 = 13; 
int pb1 = 4;
int pb2 = 5;
int pb3 = 6;
void setup() { 
pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pb1, INPUT);
pinMode(pb2, INPUT);
pinMode(pb3, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
int ledselect = random(3); 
switch (ledselect) {
case 0: //if ledcolor equals 0 then the led1 will turn on
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
if (digitalRead(pb1),HIGH)
digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
break;
case 1: //if ledcolor equals 1 then the led2 will turn on
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
if (digitalRead(pb2),HIGH)
digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
break;
case 2: //if ledcolor equals 2 then the led3 will turn on
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
if (digitalRead(pb3),HIGH)
digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two timing problems in this program: 1) loop executes too quickly to see the response, 2) the pushbutton is read before the person has time to respond to the led.

I recommend restructuring your loop() to have the following general structure:

1. Turn on an led, based on random()
2. delay to give the person time to respond. For example, delay(500); will wait 1/2 second (1000 / 2).
3. read the pushbutton, based on a second switch(ledselect) code block.
4. delay to give the person time to get ready for the next loop.  For example, delay(1000);

Comment: thankx alot bradford I catch it ,i change the circuit so I Connect all  output's switchs and connect to pin 4 in arduino (every switch become active only if his led on)

Answer (score 0):

thankx alot I catch it ,i change the circuit so I Connect all  output's switchs and connect to pin 4 in arduino (every switch become active only if his led on)

```
int ledselect = 0;
int led1 = 11; 
int led2 = 12; 
int led3 = 13; 
int pb = 4;
void setup() { 
pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pb, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
int ledselect = random(3); 
switch (ledselect) {
case 0:
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
delay(20);
while(digitalRead(pb) != HIGH){delay(20);}
digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
break;
case 1:
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
delay(20);
while(digitalRead(pb) != HIGH){delay(20);}
digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
break;
case 2:
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
delay(20);
while(digitalRead(pb) != HIGH){delay(20);}
digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
break;
default:
delay(20);
break;
}

}
```